# Makefile for pulling and building projects

Tags: git, makefile, conditional-statements

I am building a project that requires an ecosystem of projects (linux, qemu, uboot etc) most of which are in git repositories. I used to manage them all with a script but I find myself implementing stuff that is better done with make. So I decided to migrate my script to a makefile.

The problem is I want to projects to be cloned if not present and pulled if present. Is there a way to do that without repeaing myself too much?

Comment: What are the basic commands you are using in your makefile to manage working with Git repos? Can you show us a few lines as examples?

Comment: I just want to run `git clone $GIT_URL $DIR` if `$DIR` doesnt exist and `cd $DIR; git pull` if it does. Obviously each project has different pairs of `$GIT_URL` and `$DIR`... I dont know if I answered your question...

Comment: What OS, and what version of Make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work I think. It doesn't have make do the work because without depending on something inside the project directories I'm not sure you could only conditionally run the clone.

```
force: ;

proj%: force
    @echo [ -d $@ ] || git clone srv:$@
    @cd $@ && git pull
```

If you wanted to list something like `proj1/.git/config` as your entry-point prereq you could split the clone up as an order-only prereq on those with a clone for the project directory. Though you would still need the force on the config prereq to force the pull to happen.

Something like this perhaps:

```
proj%:
    git clone srv:$@

proj%/.git/config: force | proj%
    git pull
```

Comment: Can you explain this? what is force, what is proj% and how this is serving this purpose: git clone $GIT_URL $DIR if $DIR doesnt exist and cd $DIR; git pull if it does.

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a Makefile for building docker images with PHONY targets and came up with this pattern:

```
.PHONY all
all: foo-docker

foo:
        git clone https://example.org/foo-project.git $@

.PHONY: foo-update
foo-update: foo
        @cd foo && git pull

.PHONY: foo-docker
foo-docker: foo-update
        @cd foo && docker build
```